# My USB midi cable is properly connected but only one note plays at a time for about 5 seconds before it releases. What is the cause of this delay?

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard

I am using a psr E313 Yamaha keyboard.
My battery is fully charged,

The first USB midi cable I bought got me frustrated with similar challenges. The USB midi cable connects successful on my system but delays in reproducing other notes. Making it difficult to play or registar new notes in a synchronizes timing with the music.
Could it be a software problem? 
Besides, I have tried to link **midi cc in** on the properties option but it doesn't highlight. Meanwhile, in settings the **midi in** is already activated and the red and green light on the USB midi are on.
Initially I felt that I needed to turn on the PC mode 1 or 2 on my keyboard. Of which I did, yet there haven't been any improvements
What haven't I done yet to rectify this problem? Please  help

Comment: Are you running this through one of those ultra-cheap USB/Midi interfaces you can  get from eBay? That's usually the issue, if so. Buy one with a recognisable name… Yamaha, EMU, MOTU, Soundcraft etc.

Comment: Where is your sound coming from, and what device and/or application is making the sounds? If you're using a software synth in Windows, you probably also need a proper audio interface with ASIO drivers. Try Steinberg UR series or Focusrite Scarlett. Pick one that also has MIDI ports, so you can ditch the cheap USB MIDI cable, which is probably another source of problems.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "USB-midi" cable. If you’ve got something with midi (DIN 5/180°) on one side and USB on the other side that is a midi controller with USB interface. So this is a device that takes the midi signal, decodes it and provides them to the driver on the computer as digital midi events. The driver then makes these available by some standard system protocoll (i.e. as registered midi device). Thus there are multiple possible sources for the error: It could be the midi out of the keyboard, the usb midi controller or even the driver. So you should expand on your setup.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is about the "weird fantasy clef" product, most probably the problem is that your USB MIDI "cable" (adapter) is one of these:

[image: broken USB MIDI cable do not buy]

Close-up:

[image: non-working broken USB MIDI product do not buy it is crap]

This is a defective, broken product that causes trouble. According to reports, things that are broken include:

- It does not understand Running Status, so you get the problem described in the title, with Yamaha and many other devices. (Perhaps the Yamaha keyboard has a 5-second timeout after which it re-sends a status byte, and then you can play one note again)
- System Exclusive i.e. SysX data is garbled, so you can't use it for controlling MIDI devices through SysX, or recording SysX data.

To fix the problem, buy a real working USB MIDI adapter from a manufacturer/brand such as Roland, Yamaha, Steinberg, Focusrite.

There are several questions about the same defective product, but apparently that's not enough. The problem is, the broken product is still being sold, and people buy it because it's cheap. The product being broken doesn't matter, it sells anyway.

See these questions:

- [Properly set up MIDI to USB](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/100298/properly-set-up-midi-to-usb/100302#100302)
- [Why does my midi device have a long delay (cool-down period) between consecutive key presses?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/116973/why-does-my-midi-device-have-a-long-delay-cool-down-period-between-consecutive)
- [Midi/usb interface sends "note on" instead of "note off" when 2 or more keys are released at once](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/46374/midi-usb-interface-sends-note-on-instead-of-note-off-when-2-or-more-keys-are)